# Diagonal of a matrix in racket

Tags: image, dictionary, matrix, racket

I have a list of lists(matrix) and i would like to access using (`map` or `apply`) the main diagonal.

The problem is larger, to make a matrix of a list of images removing the duplicates but i did that part.

```
(make-list (length (filter (lambda (x) (<= (image-height  x) max-height)) L)) 
           (filter (lambda (x) (<= (image-height  x) max-height)) L)) )
```

I don't have a clue how to access using map or apply the elements of the main diagonal..

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `map` requires a procedure that takes as many arguments as you have lists to map. In this case we want to access the `i`th element of a list, this is the built-in procedure `list-ref` which takes a list `L` and an index `i` and returns the `i`th element of `L`. So then we just need the indexes of the diagonal elements. This is `(list 0 1 2 ...)` which we can generate using `build-list`.

```
(define (diagonal M)
  (define indexes (build-list (length M) values))
  (map list-ref M indexes))
```

You don't have to build the second list if you use recursion. In this case you build the diagonal in a recursive function where we take the leading element of the first row, then recur on the rest of the elements in the rest of the rows:

```
(define (diagonal M)
  (if (null? M)
      '()
      (cons (caar M)
            (diagonal (map cdr (cdr M))))))
```

It's going to take basically the same amount of operations in terms of building the diagonal, but the second one doesn't require a new list be generated up front and doesn't require determining the size of the matrix, so it's a little better.